# Test Report Output using Cucumber - Selenium Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, selenium, cucumber

I'm looking to have reports output from my Cucumber tests.  So far I can put the following:

```
cucumber features/feature_name.feature -f json -o C:/Reports
```

This will only produce a json report at the end of the test and you can't see the results as they're happening as you normally would with cucumber.

Can I get it to do both so that I will see the green/red steps within cmd and get the json report at the end?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add as many report formatters as you want.

To include the default "pretty" formatter and the "json" formatter:

```
cucumber features/feature_name.feature -f pretty -f json -o C:/Reports/results.txt
```

Comment: It was that simple... Should have known that!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's now recommended to use `-p json:C:/Reports/results.json`.