# Cucumber: How to get list of executed steps after each scenario?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, scenarios

After each scenario I would like to list all steps of this scenario. There is any way to do that?

Comment: Wouldn't the log/report print out all your executed steps already?

Comment: @hidro, it will. I need to store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Scenario Hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) to get steps for each scenario:

```
After do |scenario|
  scenario.steps.each { |s| puts s.to_sexp }
end
```

Comment: That's sort of what I need. How to convert steps from objects to readable strings?

Comment: Use `step.to_sexp`, then modify output to what you want, check my edit. Please accept my answer if it helps you thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I tried to_sexp and output is huge. It includes all possible information about the steps, I suppose.

Comment: Well, if that's the case you may want to check `Cucumber::Ast::StepInvocation` class to see what's available for you.

Answer (score 0):

If a report of executed scenarios is what you are after then simply set one of many types of reports formats (html, json etc) that you can specify in your CukesRunner class

See example bellow:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/cucumber-json-report.json" })
public class CukesRunner {

}
```

Comment: How to do that on Ruby?

Comment: `cucumber features/feature_name.feature -f pretty` this has already been asked and answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781478/test-report-output-using-cucumber-selenium-ruby

Comment: That's not it. I don't need to print steps. I just need to get them in after hook and do some work.